# Why is there an error in the following code?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, testunit

I would be grateful for help in sorting the error in the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

class TestGoogle < Test::Unit::TestCase    
  def setup
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  end

  def testSignInLink
    @browser.goto "http://google.com/"
    po = PageObjects.new(@browser)
    po.clickLinkSignIn
  end
end

class PageObjects
  def initialize( browser )
    @browser = browser
  end

  def clickLinkSignIn()
    @browser.link(:id, "gb_70").click
  end
end

tg = TestGoogle.new
tg.setup
tg.testSignInLink
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught exception: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:971:in `initialize'
C:/RubymineProjects/ditto/Google_01_TU_02.rb:28:in `new'
C:/RubymineProjects/ditto/Google_01_TU_02.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
```

Line 28 is:

```
tg = TestGoogle.new
```

Strangely enough, the script then runs to completion with the google login page being presented.

Note that there are no asserts yet - I'm doing this one small step at a time.

Added after edit:

The initializer in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:971

```
  def initialize name # :nodoc:
    @__name__ = name
    @__io__ = nil
    @passed = nil
  end
```

Comment: Does Test::Unit::TestCase require that you implement a top method in TestGoogle class?  IOW, is it a virtual in the base class?

Comment: `TestGoogle` is just inheriting the `initialize` from `Test::Unit::TestCase`. Does the `Test::Unit::TestCase` initializer require a parameter? Even though it appears to work, there is something in the test class which is not functioning that you are possibly just not using at the moment.

Comment: @mbratch: Here's the code for the initializer, which means almost nothing to me:

Comment: I'm referring to the `initialize` for `Test::Unit::TestCase`.

Comment: I need to use "£" instead if the instance variable symbol, which this comment is treating as a person's identifier:   def initialize name # :nodoc:
        £__name__ = name
        £__io__ = nil
        £passed = nil
      end

Comment: Why do you want to manually create an instance of the test case and run its methods (ie why are you not using the actual test/unit runner)?

Comment: Please include the `initialize` in your post, so it's easier to read it's format. It appears to me that you have a parameter `name` to `initialize`, however, you are calling `TestGoogle.new` without a parameter. That will call `initialize` with no parameter and, thus, the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`.

Comment: @mbratch I've added the intializer to the code. It's no longer relevant because of my silly use of `tg = TestGoogle.new`. But if I ever used it correctly, I don't see what `name` I could have passed.

Comment: If you write `TestGoogle` and derive it from the class `Test::Unit::TestCase` it's good to find out what the `initialize` wants. If `name` is irrelevant for some reason, then you'd override the `initialize` with your own that didn't take a parameter. Alternatively, it's possible you could get away with passing in an empty string (`""`) or `nil`.

Comment: For my own future benefit, I ran the entire original code (including the last 3 lines). I first used the empty string (""). Then I used nil. In both cases the test ran twice (a total of 4 tests). I wonder which test ran first? The test runner or the instantiated TestGoogle object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this whole question was unfair to all the good commenters.

Reason:  As an experiment, I commented out the last 3 lines of the code:

```
tg = TestGoogle.new
tg.setup
tg.testSignInLink
```

The test ran perfectly.

I was previously assuming that I needed some way to "kick start" the methods in the TestGoogle class. Similar to a "Main" program that calls all the methods in turn.

Maybe that's what @justinko was referring to? So, the TestGoogle class is a test runner?

I think I need to apologize to the commenters.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. When you `require 'test/unit'`, all of your test cases (ie children of Test::Unit::TestCase) will get run.